# How to scroll back to the top of page on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating my product pages by using the object tag code, but every time I click the "view" button, the next page is staying at the same position of previous page which I just viewed. How can I add functionality that will let me view from the top of page every time I click the "view" button?

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix"><!--! end of #sidebar -->
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <div id="content" class="defaults"><!-- navigation holder -->
        <div id="title2">Office Section</div>

        <!-- item container -->
        <ul id="itemContainer">
            <li>
                <div id="product">
                    <div id="title">FuBang®</div>
                    <div class="imageOuter" style="margin:0">
                        <a class="image" href="officesection010.html">
                            <span class="rollover" ></span>
                            <img class="imgborder" src="product/officesection/010.jpg" width="165" height="165" />
                        </a>
                    </div><br />
                    <div id="text">Sofa </div><br />
                    <div id="button">
                        <a href="officesection010.html">View Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <div id="title2"></div>
        <div class="holder"></div>
    </div>
    </div> <!--! end of #content -->
</div> <!--! end of #container -->
```

When I click the "View Details" button at a specific position "x" here: http://postimg.org/image/vgs0lwhtr/

The next page shows the same position "x", but I want it to jump to the top of page:
http://postimg.org/image/vn80e2lph/

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857007/jquery-toggle-clicking-on-link-jumps-back-to-top-of-the-page

Comment: Check :-  .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199724/scroll-to-top-javascript-in-html-website

Answer (score 12):

Using Javascript:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

Using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="#" ID="backToTop"></a>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('#backToTop').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            $('#backToTop').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
    $('#backToTop').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
        //$("html, body").scrollTop(0); //For without animation
        return false;
    });
});
```

please refere [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/540858/Smooth-Scroll-to-the-Top-of-the-Page-jQuery), may this help

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes placing scroll to body doesn't work if your current content is generated through jQuery (as it was in my case). In such situation you can just do following.

```
$(function() {
   $('html').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A small issue with Subhash's jQuery solution is that you must call this code within `$(document).ready()` in order for your `$('body')` selector to work. The `ready` event may not fire before parts of your page have been rendered to the screen.

An better approach is to simply modify the user's location as a work-around to this browser 'feature':

```
//Above all of your $(document).ready(...) code
document.location = "#";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple HTML solution for jumping between page parts**

```
// Place a tag like this where you would like to go
// in your case at the top
<a name="top"></a>

// you will reach there by click of this link  better use an image reach their by clicking on this we can also use an image, align in right 

<a href="#top">last</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Back to top button, works in all browsers.To change the scroll speed simply change the `x` in `counter -= x` here `x = 10`

```js
function scrollToTop(){
var myBody = document.body;
var id = setInterval(secondFunction,1);
var height = window.pageYOffset;
var counter = height;
function secondFunction(){
 if(window.pageYOffset == 0){
  clearInterval(id);
 }
 else {
  if(!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/g) || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g)){
  counter -= 10;
  counter--; 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = counter;
  }
  else {
   counter -= 10;
   counter--;
   myBody.scrollTop = counter;
  }
 }
}
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.backToTop {
  position: fixed;
  /* Fixed at page */
  top: auto;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
header {
   position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<!-- back to top button -->
<span class="backToTop" onclick="scrollToTop()">TOP</span>
<!-- Header -->
<header>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an id="#body" and tabindex in the `<body>` tag

```
<body id="#body" tabindex="1">
```

and use jquery focus()

```
$(function() {
    $("#body").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
function gototop() {
    if (window.scrollY>0) {
        window.scrollTo(0,window.scrollY-20)
        setTimeout("gototop()",10)
    }
}
```