# toggle on div jumping back to top of page

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a page with clickable divs that toggle content when clicked.  When the div is clicked the second time (closing the content), the page jumps back up to the top.

I see this is an issue other people have had, but all of the solutions I have found are related to the anchor tag, which is not the problem here.

I have tried changing my code per the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857007/jquery-toggle-clicking-on-link-jumps-back-to-top-of-the-page) and adding `return false;` and  `event.preventDefault();` but neither of those worked.  What am I doing wrong?

**jQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('h1').animate({"right":"147px"},3000);
        $('.more').toggle(
                function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        'z-index':'100',
                        'background-position': '41px 0px'
                        });
                    $('#heroFullColor').hide();
                    $('#heroNoColor').show();
                    $('div.' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn('fast');
                    $('.more').not(this).hide();
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-position': '0px 0px'
                            });
                    $('div.' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeOut('fast');                 
                    $('#heroNoColor, .infoWindow').hide();
                    $('#heroFullColor').fadeIn('fast');                 
                    $('.more').not(this).show();
                });
    });
```

**HTML structure (this repeats several times on the page):**

```
    <div class="more" id="franceFlag"></div>
    <div class="infoWindow franceFlag">
        <img class="imageOn" src="images/lp_foundry_on-franceFlag.jpg" width="71" height="213" alt="French Flag" id="franceFlagOn" />
        <p class="franceFlag">blah blah blah</p>
    </div>      
    <div class="more" id="heliBoth"></div>
    <div class="infoWindow heliBoth">
        <img class="imageOn" src="images/lp_foundry_on-heliBoth.jpg" width="296" height="750" alt="Helicopters" id="heliBothOn" />
        <p class="heliBoth">blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11cptbmz/) - if you scroll to the bottom right, and click on the + sign next to the flag, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Can you post a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ please?

Comment: @BobM http://jsfiddle.net/11cptbmz/ updated the question as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are hiding the element that gave your container height, then showing a different one. So it briefly has no height.

If you explicitly give your container a height, that won't happen. eg.

```
#lp-foundry-container {
height: 940px;
}
```

The same thing does not happen on the first click, because you do the hide and show instantaneously. If you were to change

```
$('#heroNoColor').show();
```

to

```
$('#heroNoColor').fadeIn('fast');
```

Like it is on the close function, then the same thing would happen on first click.

Comment: It is nice to have it explained properly. Using CSS-only fix does require a bit of thinking though, as things tend to jump around after "hide()" on carrying elements. Still this is the way to go if layout permits.

Comment: True it's often not so simple in practice - there is also the option of setting the height with javascript before you do a hide(). But CSS-only is nice if possible.

Comment: Thanks! I picked this answer because I agree - a css-only solution is nice when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

---

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('h1').animate({"right":"147px"},3000);
        $('.more').toggle(
                function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        'z-index':'100',
                        'background-position': '41px 0px'
                        });
                    $('#heroFullColor').hide();
                    $('#heroNoColor').show();
                    $('div.' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn('fast');
                    $('.more').not(this).hide();
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-position': '0px 0px'
                            });
                    $('div.' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeOut('fast');                 
                    $('#heroNoColor, .infoWindow').hide();
                    $('#heroFullColor').fadeIn('fast');                 
                    $('.more').not(this).show();
                });

                //What I added
                $(".more").click(function()
                {
                    var div = $(this);
                    $(window).scrollTop(div.offset().top).scrollLeft(div.offset().left);
                });
    });
```

Basically you are just taking the current top and left positions of the clicked div and setting the page to position itself at that point once you are done.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/11cptbmz/1/)

BTW this is a pretty cool idea, Nice job!

Comment: thanks for weighing in! This makes sense to me but went with the other solution as CSS-only is nice when possibl.e

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        ....
        $('.more').toggle(
                function(){
                   ...
                },
                function(){
                  var tempTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //<----remember Y
                  var tempLeft = $(window).scrollleft(); //<----remember X
                  .... your code here ...
                  //----> now restore the position
                  $(window).scrollTop(tempTop);
                  $(window).scrollLeft(tempLeft);

                }
        );
```